# ansible read inventory from url

Tags: ansible

I can run ansible-playbook and specify a file or a script for dynamic inventory.  For example, I've written a script that creates the inventory for ansible, I run like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i /tmp/myinventoryscript myplaybook.yaml
```

This works fine, except that I have to copy myinventoryscript to all hosts that want to do this.  myinventoryscript connects to a remote url and returns the dynamic inventory from it.

My question is does a url inventory download plugin exist anywhere?  I've looked at the supported inventory plugings for ansible, I don't see one.  However, this use case seems pretty basic.  Instead of reading the dynamic inventory from a script, or a local file, I'd like to read it from a remote file, like:

```
ansible-playbook -i https://url.for.inventory.file.com/ myplaybook.yaml
```

I just wanted something with fewer moving parts.

Comment: did you figure this out ? i'm also searching

Comment: @RickyLevi How about you Ricky?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to address this issue.

If this is a larger scale work/team supported endeavor, if at all possible use AWX/Tower to help orchestrate some of this. Your successors will thank you.

In my case, I have found during development stages I wrap my ansible-playbook calls in a script to assert the running environment is in the desired state. This might be a good place to start. I have found this is a quick way to mimic using something like AWX/Tower from your workstation without the extra fuss. It is simple to download the results of a URL as a static inventory file from a shell script via curl or wget, and if your URL takes params to affect the result, this fits that model as well.

Alternatively, consider [writing your own plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections_guide/collections_installing.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository). Collections are fairly easy to maintain and can be installed from git repos via [ansible-galaxy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections_guide/collections_installing.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository). Again, this is an extra step for anyone on their workstation to keep updated though.

Lastly, another option that has worked for me in terms of organization of playbooks in certain siloed situations, is keeping my playbooks in the same repo as my inventory scripts (static files or scripts vs plugins) and my roles/collections separate. Again, ansible-galaxy is your friend here. With a basic folder structure of:

```
|_collections/
  |_requirements.yml
|_inventory/
  |_script1
  |_script2
  |...etc
|_playbooks/
  |_playbook1.yml
  |_playbook2.yml
  |_...etc
|_roles/
  |_requirements.yml
```

You get the playbooks and inventory kind of bundled in this scenario which can be brittle, but in many situations, the playbooks are meant to run for those silos where the inventory is tightly coupled. I'm not saying this is a best practice by any means, but it does often make things easier to maintain by smaller siloed groups. Again, I generally have a run.sh script or something in the root of the project that takes the playbook name and some other params to ensure I update my local collections and roles, have other environment vars set. This generally helps new folks understand what the plays require quickly because who actually reads the READMEs :) ?

Answer (score -1):

You are assuming `https://url.for.inventory.file.com` responds with a json inventory, which might not be true (gateway timeout, internal error, 404 web pages).

It may be more secure to do this in two steps:

- curling this URL
- if the response is 200 and the downloaded json file is syntaxically correct, executing the ansible playbook.